# Cannot use C++ class inside QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I wrote simple C++ class in order to use it in QT Quick QML. Problem is that I can't use it, because: `module "org.QTPainterTest.Titler" is not installed`, but I had registered that correctly in *main.cpp* file. Class code:

```
#ifndef CTITLER_H
#define CTITLER_H


    class CTitler : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_PROPERTY(QString title READ title WRITE setTitle)
    public:
        explicit CTitler(QObject *parent = 0);
        QString title() const { return mTitle; }

    signals:

    public Q_SLOTS:
        void setTitle(QString newTitle);
    private:
        QString mTitle;
    };

#endif // CTITLER_H
```

And *main.cpp*:

```
#include "ctitler.h"
#include <QtQml/QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml/QQmlEngine>
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<CTitler>("org.QTPainterTest.Titler", 1, 0, "CTitler");
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

And QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import org.QTPainterTest.Titler 1.0
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    CTitler{
        id: test
    }


    Text {
        text: test.title
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Why this occurs? If it is revelant, i'm using newest Qt and newest QT Creator.

Comment: I did something similar here -> http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.kr/2013/06/using-qml-camera-and-passing-image-to-c.html

Comment: I did everything which is mentioned in above doc..

Comment: @OverKiller Try change uri to one without dots. I think the problem is that URI with dots are searched as plug-ins, to prevent injections in third parties modules.

Comment: @up Still does not work, QML says the same. It still cannot load it.

Comment: As for me I cannot reproduce this error. I've taked your code and it works fine without error. I only added suitable *.cpp file fot the class and added `NOTIFY` notation for the property

Comment: I don't know why, but I've created new project, copy-pasted code and ran it. Code works. Thanks for trying help me. :)

Comment: Can you please answer your own question with the solution?

Comment: Apparently there's nothing wrong in your code. Class `CTitler` is correctly declared (just one observation: For using it in QML, it would be good to include a notify signal in the property declaration). I implemented the `setTile` slot and tested your code on 5.3.0 and it works well (as expected). So, if there's a problem it should be on your Qt version or in some code you're not showing, or just black magic. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've recreated project with that class. It works. The problem were with the previous project. I dunno what was wrong.